# Can Merkle tree tell if more than one copy of the object exist in it?

Tags: data-structures, blockchain, merkle-tree

With Merkle root hash, and Merkle path, one can verify if a given object (i.e a transaction) exist in a Merkle tree. But is it possible to tell there is no other duplication of the object in the tree.

For example, if I have the Merkle root of a list of transactions and the Merkle path of one transaction. Then, I can verify if my transaction exist in the Merkle tree, but can I also tell there is only one such transaction, not two?

Answer (score 0):

With merkle root, merkle path and transaction id, NO.

But you can check the transaction list in a block and see if there is only one such transaction in the block.